# Windows 8 in Automatic Repair loop. Can't boot from disk, either.

Tags: windows-8, boot

My Windows 8 install will not boot. Sometimes it just looks like it's loading forever, and then eventually either pops up a blue error screen, which goes away too quickly for me to see it, or a black screen, and just sits there. After reboot, it'll say it's "Preparing Automatic Repair. This fails as well, with a screen that goes away too fast for me to see it. I thought I'd try booting from disk, but that doesn't work either, as it appears to take time loading, but ends with a black screen that doesn't load anything.

Comment: Do you get a boot menu that looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/1fjOv.png by chance? You can also press `Shift` + `F8` to get the menu.

Comment: I do not get such a screen, and no, you cannot use that key combination to get the menu. They took that out after the Community Preview.

Comment: I figured that.   Without the BSOD message is going to be very dificult to propose solutions.

Comment: Is there some key I can hold to make the blue screen stay up, and not disappear right away? On a side note, it seems to be an unbelievably stupid decision to make the machine restart right away so one can't see the message.

Comment: Without the ability to boot you will be unable to modify the setting that changes this behavior.  Its not normally set the way its currently set.

Comment: Is there some explanation for why I can't boot from CD? While a driver might be causing the system to not boot, I can't imagine booting from CD would be using the system drivers.

Comment: I don't know how you made the disk nor what the disk contents were exactly.  You should be able to load a recovery disk thats the purpose of them.

Comment: It's the disk in retail packaging I bought from Microsoft.

Comment: I have several hundred disk from Microsoft.  What does it say on the lable?0

Comment: Windows 8 Pro, 64 bit.